# Android Login not connecting with DB

Tags: java, android, mysql, database

I'm using [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) to make an Android login application. I have followed all his steps and successfully am able to load the application on the emulator or my phone, however when I try and create an account I get an error - I followed the instructions he provided stating how to test the system, referencing to here:

> 5. Testing the App
>
> For a beginner it will be always difficult to run this project for the first time. But don’t worry, the following steps will helps you testing this app. (The ip address looks like 192.168.0.100)
>
> Make sure that both devices (the device running the PHP project and the android device) are on the same wifi network.
>
> Give correct username , password and database name of MySQL in Config.php
>
> Replace the URL ip address of URL_LOGIN and URL_REGISTER in AppConfig.java with your machine ip address. You can get the ip address by running ipconfig in cmd

my IPv4 address is 192.168.0.11,
So I added that to the AppConfig file as follows:

```
package android.loginfirstattempt.com.loginfirstattempt.app;


public class AppConfig {
    // Server user login url
    public static String URL_LOGIN = "http://192.168.0.11/android_login_api/login.php";


    // Server user register url
    public static String URL_REGISTER = "http://192.168.0.11/android_login_api/register.php";

}
```

I am using Android Studio's built in emulator so both devices are on the same network.

I am using Lampp and I'm under the assumption by default this is the username and password:

```
<?php
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
define("DB_DATABASE", "android_api");
?>
```

I started the local servers and tested to make sure they were running by loading up a demo page.

I've already also created the MySQL database and table as shown in his example.

My file structure for the server side is shown in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raiYw.png)

But when I try create a User I get this crash:

> ```
>                                                                                          beginning of crash
> ```
>
> 06-26 19:12:13.205 2668-2668/android.loginfirstattempt.com.loginfirstattempt E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                                  Process: android.loginfirstattempt.com.loginfirstattempt, PID: 2668
>                                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.loginfirstattempt.com.loginfirstattempt.app.AppController.addToRequestQueue(com.android.volley.Request, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                                      at android.loginfirstattempt.com.loginfirstattempt.activity.RegisterActivity.registerUser(RegisterActivity.java:189)
>                                                                                                      at android.loginfirstattempt.com.loginfirstattempt.activity.RegisterActivity.access$300(RegisterActivity.java:35)
>                                                                                                      at android.loginfirstattempt.com.loginfirstattempt.activity.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:84)
>                                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
>                                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

I am unable to find any obvious error and was wondering if someone could help!

Comment: Here is an image of the phpmyadmin page for the db and table http://i.stack.imgur.com/KJUgQ.png

Comment: Here is the project if you would like to take a look https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4vL9wnJulKoVUt6bmNPNjJXUUk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i added a link in my comment below, which might be a solution to your last error.

Comment: @Rockney I ended up coding my own version of the project from scratch thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't add the AppController to the application tag in the AndroidManifest.xml as explained in the tutorial. Your AppController now doesn't get called during the initialization of your app and isn't initialized. When you call `AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);` inside your `registerUser` method `AppController.getInstance()` returns null. This causes your nullpointerException. Add the AppController to the manifest and your code should be working.

Your application tag should look like this:

```
 <application
    android:name="com.loginfirstattempt.app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: Hi, thanks that fixed it - however when i try register now I get this error http://pastebin.com/9zZnvQ4F

Comment: I added in the internet permission yet still get an error http://pastebin.com/Y4qqUXzY ... i do not undetstand why it cant be found - its in the correct directory you can see from the screenshot in the question

Comment: You can refer to your host in multiple ways. You could try using 127.0.0.1 or localhost instead of 192.168.0.11

Comment: hey, thanks yes I figured that error out after posting it but I do not understand this one! could you take a look at this one last one please?! http://pastebin.com/RxucFbq2    this is when i try to register

Comment: anyone able to help?

Comment: did you start your url with http://? Someone has got a similar error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37682018/null-pointer-error-in-jsonobjectrequest and he didn't add http:// to his url.